# LWC - Iterate through rows of lightning datatable using javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Are we able to iterate through the rows of a lighting datatable and query each columns value in Javascript?

Like this, but for a lightning datatable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript

I would imagine it's something like below, but this doesn't work obviously.

```
var rows = this.template.querySelector('my-custom-datatable');
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   }  
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? do you want to get selected rows?

Comment: No. I do not want to get the selected rows. This is for a hotfix. I want to only change the value of particular cell(s). I know I could refactor the Apex I'm using to initially retrieve/manipulate the data but this is a larger effort. I was checking to see if I could iterate through each row and cell, compare the value of that cell and if its fulfills my condition(s), then change it's value.

Comment: Can you provide Playground link? also why not just use the array that you used to create table manually in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to get the `lightning-datatable`  using template.querySelector and then access the `rows` attribute

```
 iterateOverTable(event){        
        var table = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        var rows = table.data;
        rows.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element.name);
        });

    }
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Nh9CElBEE/1/edit

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you. Just a thing of note for anyone using this as I easily overlooked it. Use 'element.<field-name-of-column>' to access a specific columns value.

Comment: I think this only gives visible data, right? Like if pagination is involved, then this will fail.

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the returned data from your apex controller and then point that property as your edited data to your lightning-datatable.

This is for **aura** but the idea is the same:

```
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let resultData = response.getReturnValue();
            if (resultData !== null) {

                resultData.forEach(function (record) {
                    if (typeof record.Id != 'undefined') {
                        if (record.IsActive) {
                            record.displayIconName = 'utility:check';
                            record.showClass = 'greencolor'
                        } else {
                            record.displayIconName = 'utility:close';
                            record.displayIconName = 'redcolor';
                        }
                    }
                });

                component.set("v.data", resultData);
```

Comment: is this AURA, OP has asked for LWC

Comment: Actually I found a way to do this for LWC using cellAttribute and slds-text-title_bold https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

Comment: I created a wrapper in Apex which sets .slds-text-title_bold to an @auraenabled field that is treated as a cellAttribute. in the JS controller in column just define it as they have mentioned . then in my imperative apex call from LWC JS controller I iterate throw the rows using a for .  then i use an if condition to single out that row

Comment: as in if  this.resultdata[i]=='thelastrow' then i add that additional attribute in the assignment eg 
 this.rowdata=[... this.rowdata, { fieldname:result[i].fieldname, }